# how check the json array contains repeated values in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, async-await

```
var values = {[
    { name: 'jerem' },
    { name: 'jio' },
    { name: 'paul' },
    { name: 'jio' }}
];

var valueArr = values.map(function(item){ return item.name });
var isDuplicate = valueArr.some(function(item, idx){ 
    return valueArr.indexOf(item) != idx 
});
console.log(isDuplicate);
```

How to write the above code using promise all and async? can someone help me here

Comment: Why do you want to do this in an async method?  And other posters answered your title question but not the question you asked below your code.  Can you clarify what you would like to have answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const filtered = values.filter(ele => ele.name == "YOUR_CONDITION");
if(filtered.length > 1){
  // array contains duplicate elements.
}
```

Comment: Please, add some description.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of solutions to find the duplicate objects from an array

Solution 1:

```
 var values = [
    { name: 'someName1' },
    { name: 'someName2' },
    { name: 'someName1' },
    { name: 'someName1' }
]

// solution
var hasDuplicate = false;
values.map(v => v.name).sort().sort((a, b) => {
  if (a === b) hasDuplicate = true
})
console.log('hasDuplicate', hasDuplicate)
```

Solution 2nd: If you are in an environment which supports ECMA Script 6's Set, then you can use Array.prototype.some and a Set object, like this

```
let seen = new Set();
var hasDuplicates = values.some(function(currentObject) {
    return seen.size === seen.add(currentObject.name).size;
});
```