# How to find the duplicate values in JSON array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

From the array test the two objects with `"id": 3` should be evaluated as a duplicte

```json
{ "test": [
           {"id": 8, "num": 11 },
           {"id": 3, "num": 10 },
           {"id": 3, "num": 12 },
  ]
}
```

How to find objects in a json array where a certain attribute (here `id`) has the same value (here `3`)?

Comment: Apart from the id, I see no repeated value, num is unique in each field, could you be more specific ? Please show us what you have tried too :)

Comment: @jo_va here the same `id` should not repeat if so it should return an error

Comment: Use a simple `for` loop and add each `id` to an array or a `Set`. Check if the current `id` in context exists in the array. Have you tried anything? Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Comment: please add the code, you tried and the wanted result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if the array of objects have duplicate property values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30735465/how-can-i-check-if-the-array-of-objects-have-duplicate-property-values)

Answer (score 8):

We can do so by making use of [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

The short version is this

```js
const hasDuplicate = obj.test.some(element =>idSet.size === idSet.add(element.id).size)
```

A simplyfied example

```js
const myArray = [{"id": 5},{"id": 6},{"id": 7},{"id": 7},{"id": 8}];
var idSet = new Set();
const hasDuplicate = myArray.some(element =>idSet.size === idSet.add(element.id).size);
// elements are added until the first duplicate was found; 
// that is the reason why id=8 is not in the set
let allEntries = "";
for (const entry of idSet.entries()) {
  allEntries += entry + ", "   
}
console.log(allEntries);
```

Your example with console.log to illustrate what goes on

```js
const obj = { "test": [
           { "id": 7, "num": 112},
           { "id": 8, "num": 11},
           { "id": 3, "num": 10 },
           { "id": 3, "num": 12 },
           { "id": 9, "num": 12 }
        ]};
const idSet = new Set(); // a Set stores unique values of any type
// for each element in test[] try to add the id to idSet 
const hasDuplicate = obj.test.some(element => {                       
  console.log("id ", element.id, " is already in set: ", idSet.has(element.id));
  // returns true for the first duplicate and terminates .some()
  return (idSet.size === idSet.add(element.id).size)
});

console.log("hasDuplicate =", hasDuplicate); // returns true for 2nd id = 3
```

What we are trying to achieve here is

- we try to add each object from the `obj.test` array into the Set `idSet`
- every entry within the Set element must be unique.

If and when duplicated `id`s are found, it cannot be added to the Set. Therefore, the size of the Set, `unique`, will not increase for that iteration, and thus, it will cause Array.some() to return true, which denotes that there is indeed a duplicated `id`.

Comment: you check this url  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55968654/how-check-the-json-array-contains-repeated-values-in-nodejs

Comment: in above addition i want index also for duplicated vale of latest item index

Comment: works like charm!